# Estimating the length of a curve with the Cauchy-Crofton formula

Tags: differential-geometry, convergence-divergence, curves, arc-length, integral-geometry

This is a comment from Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces:

> Equation $\iint n dp d\theta=2l$ (where $n$ is thenumber of intersection points of a curve $C$ with all straight lines in the plane that meet $C$) can also be used to obtain an efficient way of estimating
> lengths of curves. Indeed, a good approximation for the integral $\iint n dp d\theta$
> is given as follows. Consider a family of parallel straight lines such that
> two consecutive lines are at a distance $r$. Rotate this family by angles of
> $\pi/4, 2\pi/4, 3\pi/4$ in order to obtain four families of straight lines. Let $n$ be the
> number of intersection points of a curve $C$ with all these lines. Then $\frac{1}{2}{nr} \frac{\pi}{4}$ is an approximation to the integral $ \iint n dp d\theta=\hbox{length of }C$.

**My question:** How can I prove it and if it is true that $\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{2}n(r)r\frac{\pi}{4}=\hbox{length of }C$?

I couldn't understand how the author arrived at the formula $\frac{1}{2}{nr} \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Why are you saying the curve is non-rectifiable? Then length makes no sense.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't make sense. I tried to reproduce what the author said but it was out of context.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you tell me if these claims are proven anywhere?

Comment: It's just a heuristic and an approximation. There is no rigorous limiting equality unless you also allow $\pi/4$ to approach $0$.  You might try working it out for the case of a line segment. I don't believe you get equality at all then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ultimate reference on integral geometry, Santaló's *Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability*, he gives this formula, originally due to Steinhaus (one reference is "Length, shape and area," *Colloq. Math.* **3** (1954), 1-13), on pp. 31-32. If we turning the grid through multiples of $\pi/m$, we obtain
$$\ell\approx \frac{N\pi r}{2m}.$$
If we let $r\to 0$ and $m\to\infty$, then we can suspect with some hypotheses that this is calculating  the integral $\dfrac12\iint n\,dp\,d\theta$.

Here's a reference for the error estimates: P.A.P. Moran, "Measuring the length of a curve," *Biometrika* **53** (1966), 359-364.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the references! The comments made by Do Carmo were very informal.

Comment: The point is that if you rotate by $\pi/m$ and think of $m$ as large, then you really see the Riemann sum approximation with $\sum n_i\Delta p\Delta\theta = (\sum n_i)(r)(\pi/m) = N\pi r/m \approx 2\ell$.